# jquery Ajax $.ajaxError

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of ajax calls that contain success and error conditions like this one:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Remote/State.cfc'
        ,type: "POST"
        ,data: {
            'method': 'UpdateStateName'
            ,'StateID': StateID
            ,'StateName': StateName
        }
        ,success: function(result){
            if (isNaN(result)) {
                $('#msg').text(result).addClass('err');
            } else {
                $('#' + result + ' input[name="StateName"]').addClass('changed');
            };
        }
        ,error: function(msg){
            $('#msg').text('Connection error').addClass('err');
        }
    });
```

All the error conditions are the same.  In other words, they all put the phrase "Connection error" in the msg id.

Q1: Could I remove all these and replace them with

```
$().ajaxError(function(myEvent, request, settings, thrownError) {
    $('#msg').text('Connection error').addClass('err');
});
```

Q2: How would you use myEvent and request to display a more informative error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q1.  You can use [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) like this:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function() {
  $('#msg').text('Connection error').addClass('err');
});
```

...or if the `#msg` element is present the entire time, you can do this:

```
$('#msg').ajaxError(function() {
  $(this).text('Connection error').addClass('err');
});
```

Q2. You can use the handler's arguments that `ajaxError` passes in, it uses this format:
`handler(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions, thrownError)`, something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, options, error) {
  $('#msg').addClass('err')
     .text('Connection error: ' + error + ' when connecting to ' + options.url);
});
```

*Note:* in previous versions of jQuery this would be done via `$.ajaxError()`, since 1.7 that's no longer the case, you'll need to attach it to a jQuery object you want it on, or `document` if you don't care about a particular element.

Comment: $.ajaxError is "not found" in jQuery 1.7.1. $(document).ajaxError works though...

Comment: $.ajaxError(function()  doesnt work, as pointed out. Has to be attached to element, like "document"

Comment: @Aleja_Vigo - indeed, this is a breaking change in jQuery long after this answer was posted :)