# global ajaxError handler jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling

on Jquery websites says that i should attach ajaxError method to some html elemnt.

It means i have to have such element. But i wont use it.

I want to have one global handler which will handle all ajax error messages.

I've tried like here [jquery Ajax $.ajaxError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587262/jquery-ajax-ajaxerror)

but i'm getting error message

http://o7.no/xnbFsj

and line 16 is

http://o7.no/xlLVPI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to attach the handler to any element. And to make it global:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(){...
```

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Answer (score 1):

How about attaching it to the `document`:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
    ...
});
```